# JQuery mouseout timeout

Tags: jquery, mouse, effects, fade, mouseenter

Similar problems have been dealt with before but I believe mine's slightly different owing to the use of the bind() function. Anyhow...

```
$('.overlay').bind("mouseenter",function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0);
}).bind("mouseleave",function(){                
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
  }, 2000);
});
```

I want to fade out the overlay on "mouseenter", but only fade it back in 2000ms after "mouseleave".

I have an additional question: When the .overlay div fades out, I need to be able to click on what's beneath it i.e. I need the div to disappear completely or move down the z-index stack. However, if I try adding this in, the script thinks the mouse has left the .overlay div, so the .overlay fades back in.

For the same reason I can't use fadeOut() and fadeIn().

Comment: added an additional question...

Answer (score 2):

When the timeout fires `this` won't be what you expect.  You can create a closure like this:

```
            $('.overlay').bind("mouseenter",function(){
                    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0);
                    }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
                    var $this = $(this);                               
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                            $this.fadeTo('slow', 1);
                            }, 2000);
            });
```

Comment: Two questions: does the '$' in `var $this = ...` have any significance? And what would `$(this)` be referring to in his original code that you got around here?

Comment: No, the `$` in `var $this` is just to make the variable look more jQueryish. The `$` character has no special meaning in javascript. And its only an alias for "jQuery" in jQuery.

Comment: works fine, thanks - I see now that the $(this) wrapped inside the setTimeout function refers to something different.

Comment: OK I have an additional question:

When the .overlay div fades out, I need to be able to click on what's beneath it i.e. I need the div to disappear completely or move down the z-index stack. However, if I try adding this in, the script thinks the mouse has left the .overlay div, so the .overlay fades back in.

For the same reason I can't use fadeOut() and fadeIn().